# Are reals with discrete metric a $F$ space.

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, continuity

Let $X$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$. If there is a metric $d$ such that:
1)$(X,d)$ is complete metric space
2)$d(x+z,y+z)=d(x,y)$ for all $x,y,z$.
3)functions $(x_1,x_2)\to x_1+x_2 $ and $(\lambda,x)\to \lambda x$ are continous
then $X$ is $F$-space

Check this conditions for $\mathbb{R}$ with discrete metrics.

I have no problem with the first two, since in 1) it is enough to choose $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ and all Cauchy sequences will be "eventually" constant, so they will be convergent.

The second one is also true I think for obvious reasons.

But could you suggest me how to deal with 3)?

Comment: In (3), when you say $(\lambda,x)\to \lambda x$ is continuous, what topology are you using?  This is a map $\mathbb{K}\times X\to X$, so you need some choice of a topology on $\mathbb{K}$.  For $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric, are you putting the discrete metric on $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ as well, or the usual metric?

Comment: The usual one I guess.

Comment: Would changing it to discrete metric help?

I am stuck with the multiplication function, since I don't really know that norm on $\mathbb{R}xX$.